# What is the meaning of "added ... commits" to GitLab merge request

Tags: git, gitlab

I have trouble understanding semantically what happens with commits associated to GitLab merge requests.

As an example, consider [this merge request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/9000). At the top of the request, it says "Discussion: 9, Commits: 1, ...". Further down, however, there is a comment that says

> Dmitriy Zaporozhets @dzaporozhets added 358 commits 2 weeks ago

What happened (in Git terms) that made this comment to appear? How can I resolve the seeming contradiction that the Merge Request is about just *one* commit, but later several hundreds were added?

Answer (score 0):

Because they could have been a [`rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description) from another branch into master. The other branch having 358 commits.

Look at the description of this PR:

> - Branch has no merge conflicts with master (if it does - rebase it
>     please)

Comment: Would it really be a rebase? Since the branch has already been pushed to the server, wouldn't the commits be a result of a _merge_ of `master` into the current branch?

Comment: Yes it could be a `merge`. Anyhow is not very uncommon (in my experience) dealing with old branches, to merge `master` into the `featured` branch. This avoid to solve conflict directly in `master` (I don't know if I'm clear here ^^)

Comment: But we can't know for sure what it is, except if you can have a look at the logs